# Use /graphicspath twice in document

Tags: graphics, paths

Dear all i want to use `/graphicspath` twice in my document. Once in the `preample.sty` file I created and once in a `user_settings.tex` document for additional user input. But if I use `/graphicspath` a second time  it doesn't work.
One a side note is there a way to include all subdirectorys in a given path?

```
/graphicspath{{./dir//}}
```

used to work but it doesn´t anymore

Comment: `//` never worked in graphicspath, however it works in TEXINPUTS that you can set before calling tex, and is usually more efficient than using graphics[ath

Comment: `\graphicspath` is just a local declaration you can use it as often as you like and it has scope the surrounding environment or group.

Comment: Re. subdirectories: you can specify subdirectories relative to a declared `\graphicspath`; e.g., if you declare `\graphicspath{{/pictures/mine/}{/graphics/other/}}`, you can include `/pictures/mine/summer/vacation.png` with `summer/vacation.png` and `/graphics/other/winter/sledding.pdf` with `winter/sledding.pdf`. I don't think there is a way to do away with specifying subdirectories (summer and winter in this example). Even if there is, you may well just end up confusing yourself by including the wrong image. That is just the kind of minor time saving that comes back to bite you.